# Change display from ID to Name

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository, repository-pattern

I have 2 Models, and I want it to show the Name of the Faculty instead of the ID shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nohgy.png)

I am displaying the User's own Article that has submitted it.

How can I change an ID to a Name Faculty that contains that ID?

Comment: Your Model contains the Faculty name. What keeps you from just using that as value for the Faculty column?

Comment: I tried adding it just recently. I don't think I'll use it

Comment: I want it to be displayed by the NameFaculty itself created at the Model Faculty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your repository by including the foreign key columns like this

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetPersonalArticles(string userName)
{
    return _dbContext.Articles.Include(a=>a.Faculty).Where(a => a.Author == userName).ToList();
}
```

Comment: We are still missing something so it can display Name.

Comment: Have you tried using Falculty.Name  rather than just Falculty in your views

Comment: @Moojc Have you tried Faculty.Name as your data for the column (after including the Faculty navigation property in the repository query). Check out: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html

Comment: I tried changing facultyId to facultyName, but it failed

Comment: Replace your code with this  { data: 'faculty.Name' , title: 'Faculty'  },

Comment: Dont forget the dot inbetween the faculty & Name